# angularjs display mysql 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, mysqli

[ASK]
I have 2 table in MySql database

```
|Questions|
------------------------------
questionID|question|answer


|Options|
------------------------------
Id|questionID|option|result
```

i want to display the table like this on angularjs

```
questionID -> question -> - Option1
                          - Option2 (Answer)
                          - Option3
                          - Option4
```

I know the query of that.. but the problem is when i load to angular cannot load properly so i just want to know that how to load to angular using php??

Answer (score 1):

We can do two different way one write Web service using Restful or SOAP and other method using PHP, pull the data from table and frame JSON object to consume from AngularJS. In AngularJS write HTTP request in service layer like below.

```
getQuestions: function(){
    $http.get("http://example.com/questions.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });  
}
```

questions.php JSON output

```
[
   {
      "questionId":"123",
      "question":"Your question",
      "options":[
         {
            "option":'Option1',
            "correct":false
         },
         {
            "option":'Option2',
            "correct":false
         },
         {
            "option":'Option3',
            "correct":true
         },
         {
            "option":'Option4',
            "correct":false
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "questionId":133,
      "question":"Your question1",
      "options":[
         {
            "option":'Option1',
            "correct":false
         },
         {
            "option":'Option2',
            "correct":true
         },
         {
            option:'Option3',
            "correct":false
         },
         {
            "option":'Option4',
            "correct":false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

https://github.com/kalaikt/pooling/blob/master/webservice/libs/pooling.php
https://github.com/kalaikt/pooling/blob/master/app/services/customersService.js

Comment: i still confused in query in questions.php, when i encode like "echo json_encode($data);" then display just question and questionID but not the option and answe

Comment: Updated my answer and also refer my Github you will get idea.